# Firebase - how to enumerate all child values' contents?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android app in Android Studio which lists events based on categories (music, sport, business, theatre). Every event has a name, description, location and time. This is how the events are stored in Firebase when a user posts events through my application:
[image: Screenshot]

How can I retrieve e.g. all childs and its contents in the Music category? I have four String arrays to display events (currently manually) like this:

```
String[] name = {"Eminem","Rihanna"};
String[] desc = {"Concert","Live Show"};
String[] location = {"Miami","Florida"};
String[] time = {"bllablla","bllablla"};
```

I want to populate the string arrays automatically from firebase, however I'm not sure how to get contents for every child element from Music element? If needed, I can post the Java code which populates the database as well.

Edit: I've tried this:

```
DatabaseReference info = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child("Music");
info.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot val: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      // Retreive all Music childs and then retreive all data of them childs?
     }
     @Override
     public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to retrieve the items from firebase ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout Edited my post. Stuck here for hours (new at Firebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no easier solution than to download all of your music data, loop through all children and create corresponding arrays manually -

**1) Create a class to map your firebase music record to -**

```
class MusicRecord{
    String date;
    String eventDescription;
    String eventName;
    String location;
}
```

**2) Load data, loop through children, retrieve MusicRecords and populate your arrays**

```
protected void loadData(){
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Events").child("Music");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> recordsSnaphots = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            int count = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int i = 0;

            String[] names = new String[count];
            String[] descriptions = new String[count];
            String[] locations = new String[count];
            String[] times = new String[count];

            for(DataSnapshot recordSnapshot: recordsSnaphots){
                MusicRecord record = recordSnapshot.getValue(MusicRecord.class);
                if(record != null) {
                    names[i] = record.eventName;
                    descriptions[i] = record.eventDescription;
                    locations[i] = record.location;
                    times[i] = record.date;

                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your post, you'll have to do several things :

1. **Create a model**

You'll have to create a POJO that describes the structure of the data you have in your Firebase realtime database. In your case, create a class `FirebaseEvent` that has a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and three Strings (eventDescription,eventName,location).

2. **Instantiate your class**

Based on your last snippet, instantiate your class with the data from your Firebase realtime database. Firebase API is still a bit tedious with this, but this is yet the most common way to do it

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {   
    GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,FirebaseEvent>> ti = 
        new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,FirebaseEvent>>() {};

    HashMap<String,FirebaseEvent> retrievedEvents = childSnapshot.getValue(ti);
}
```

Now, what you have is a HashMap with keys like "Eminem" and "Rihanna" and the corresponding value that is a `FirebaseEvent`.

Comment: Isn't it sad that I'm close to graduating from a computer engineering uni., and I never heard about HashMap from our lectures (we develop mostly in Java, for 2 years now). Thanks for checking this out, I learned a thing or two from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I choose to use an ArrayList for a dynamic data structure.
I also took a snapshot of my database:
[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> name= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> location= new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> date= new ArrayList<String>();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    public static final String TAG= "YOUR-TAG-NAME";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child("Music");
        // Read from the database
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                for (DataSnapshot values: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //query for the parent of the date "Eminem"
                    String key = values.getKey().toString();
                    name.add(key);
                    //query for location in the music category
                    date.add(values.child("location").getValue().toString());
                    //query for date in the music category
                    date.add(values.child("date").getValue().toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your solution